# Is there a way to automatically confirm PyCharm User Agreement pop-up window?

Tags: python, automation, pycharm, project

i am using pycharm.sh script on the Linux system to automate opening project in PyCharm. My problem is that i don't know how to manage to automatically confirm the PyCharm User Agreement window. Every time i run the script for the frist time it always asks to click the confirm button and then the project opens up.
Is there a way to automatically set it up in the script or to use another way to automatically continue in this window?

The only thing i've tried was to manually click the confirm the button, then the project window opens up and i don't know another workaround.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.